# Google+ Over-The-Air installs with oAuth 2.0 protocol

Tags: android, google-plus, over-the-air

Here (https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs) is described how to make over-the-air Android installs using HTML button.

I wonder how to do the same using oAuth 2.0 flow (the docs --https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent -- doesn't provide information about it).

Which additional parameter(s) I have to add to endpoint request ([https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?%20scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&%20state=/profile&%20redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback&%20response_type=token&%20client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com)) to make it show over-the-air-install dialog?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is only available through the Google+ Sign-In client-side button, which handles the creation of the OAuth flow. You can use the JavaScript gapi.signin.render() method to create a [custom button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#customizing_the_sign-in_button) if you prefer not to use the standard Google+ Sign-In button. However, the feature is not accessible in any other way such as a server-side OAuth flow.